# Microsoft bot Proactive messaging - cannot convert from group to string - IMessageActivity to string

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to implement the bot that proactively sends message to the user by interrupting with a prompt dialog as per 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages

I have below LUIS method implementation which works perfectly, it interrupts user during conversation as the per timer set, which is 3 seconds-
So, after 3 seconds, bot interrupts user with another prompt (not added in the code below - it is just a prompt that gives 2 options to user - Stay in the proactive prompt or Go back to previous conversation).

```
    [LuisIntent("MyIntent")]
    public async Task MyIntent(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> res, LuisResult result)
    {
        var message = await res;
        try
        {
            await context.PostAsync("I see that you have below options <br/> 1. Do first task <br/> 2. Do second task <br/> 3. Do third task " + count);

            var conversationReference = message.ToConversationReference();
            ConversationStarter.conversationReference = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(conversationReference);

            //Prepare the timer to simulate a background/asynchonous process
            t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(timerEvent));
            t.Change(3000, Timeout.Infinite);

            var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
            //We echo the message regardless
            await context.PostAsync("In a few seconds I'll interrupt this dialog and bring another one with a prompt.");
            PromptDialog.Text(context, taskdoer, "You can ask me like - <br/>Do task 2<br/>or simply enter 2");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Error is <br/> " + e.ToString());
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
    }

    private async Task taskdoer(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        string strTaskNumber = await result;
                if (strTaskNumber == "2")
                {
                    await context.PostAsync("So, you have entered  " + strTaskNumber);
                    await context.PostAsync("This is Task 2");
                    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
                }
                if (strTaskNumber == "3")
                {
                    await context.PostAsync("So, you have entered  " + strTaskNumber);
                    await context.PostAsync("This is Task 3");
                    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
                }
    }
```

What I would like to achieve is, implement the timer for proactive dialog to come in with in the taskdoer method when user enters 2. like below -

```
    private async Task taskdoer(IDialogContext context,IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> res, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        string strTaskNumber = await result;
                if (strTaskNumber == "2")
                {

                    await context.PostAsync("So, you have entered  " + strTaskNumber);
                    await context.PostAsync("This is Task 2");
        var message = await res;
            await context.PostAsync("I see that you have below options <br/> 1. Do first task <br/> 2. Do second task <br/> 3. Do third task " + count);

            var conversationReference = message.ToConversationReference();
            ConversationStarter.conversationReference = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(conversationReference);

            //Prepare the timer to simulate a background/asynchonous process
            t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(timerEvent));
            t.Change(3000, Timeout.Infinite);

            var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
            //We echo the message regardless
            await context.PostAsync("In a few seconds I'll interrupt this dialog and bring another one with a prompt.");
            PromptDialog.Text(context, taskdoer, "You can ask me like - <br/>Do task 2<br/>or simply enter 2");            
                    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
                }
                ....
    }
```

When I do this way, I get error "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'ResumeAfter'" 
So, I couldnt use IMessageActivity in taskdoer. Any leads on how can I achieve proactive message in taskdoer method upon user input 2 in MyIntent method?

Answer (score 0):

The `ResumeAfter<T>` method of a `Prompt` must always have only two parameters: the `IDialogContext` and the `IAwaitable<T>` (where the result of the `Prompt` will be). In your case `T`, is a `string` since you are using PromptDialog.Text.

So you can't pass `IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>` res. If for some reason you need the original activity you can use `context.Activity`.